# ULONG_PTR in Python ctypes

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

I use the Python ctypes library on Windows and implement an [OVERLAPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. It has 2 members of ULONG_PTR type that is not available in ctypes.wintypes. According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384264(v=vs.85).aspx) ULONG_PTR is a ULONG which depends on the pointer size. Can I use wintypes.ULONG instead of ULONG_PTR in Python or is there a better approach?

I found several different implementations of OVERLAPPED structure: [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/sandbox/libraries/slpmonkeypatch/resources/iocp.py) POINTER(ULONG)) is used instead of ULONG_PTR and [here](https://github.com/kofemann/dcapsync/blob/master/watchdog/observers/winapi.py) - LPVOID. But ULONG_PTR is not a pointer so IMHO these are not the right types to use. Am I wrong? I tried LPVOID and it works, but I am not a C guy, so I wonder is there any difference in my case?

Comment: `POINTER(ULONG)` is wrong and apparently comes from misunderstanding the `_PTR` suffix. There's no need to guess; just [look up the data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751#ULONG_PTR) on MSDN.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about when I saw those examples. _PTR is not a pointer. I chose ULONG because I have missed WPARAM in wintypes. Now I realize that I also made a mistake, because I am on 64-bit system and c_ulonglong should have been used instead. Maybe you can transform your comment about WPARAM into an answer?

Comment: The current answer is good. I just wanted to clarify that using `c_void_p` is wrong in cases where one wants a 0 value instead of `None`, such as `InternalHigh`. Also, using `WPARAM` saves a couple of lines, but the end result is the same as the code in the answer that conditionally assigns `c_ulonglong` vs `c_ulong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `c_void_p` or `LPVOID`. This will be whatever size a pointer is and the actual type doesn't matter since you'll never access the `Internal` and `InternalHigh` members.

Using `POINTER(ULONG)` would work, but so would `POINTER(c_char)` or any other pointer type. The type is still wrong, except now you're allocating a new type object that you don't actually need.

If you need to access the internal members using their "correct" types then you'd need to define one of two different OVERLAPPED structures depending on whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python.  Something like:

```
if ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) == 8:
    ULONG_PTR = ctypes.u_longlong
else:
    ULONG_PTR = ctypes.u_long

class OVERLAPPED(ctypes.Structure): 
    _fields_ = [("Internal", ULONG_PTR),
                ("InternalHigh", ULONG_PTR),
                ...]
```

Comment: Using `c_void_p` is incorrect if you need the type's `getfunc` to return 0 instead of `None`. The `getfunc` is called for the object `value`, function results, and accessing struct fields and array/pointer indexes. The integer definition is more generally correct. You can alias `ULONG_PTR = ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM`, which is conditionally defined based on the pointer size.

Comment: @Ross Ridge, thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate on how incorrect type in my scenario can affect the execution or correctness? I see that technically they will all work, but how can they change the program behaviour?

Comment: @wombatonfire It won't affect program behaviour unless you access the internal members in some way. Since they're for internal use only, you're not supposed to setting them or reading them. If you don't access the internal members then any type that reserves enough space for these members (eg. `c_char * 4` for the 32-bit case) will work. That's why you see the variation in implementations, anything of the correct size will work in practice.